# include IPython Notebook in my stackoverflow post

Tags: stack-overflow, ipython

I can add code using the blockquotes in Stackoverflow, but it is also possible to include or embed my IPython notebook into my post on stackoverflow? Since in some cases it is much clearer

Comment: I think for now the best you can do is to put it on nbviewer and post the link in your question.

Comment: This is really a feature request (so belongs on meta).

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I found in addition to nbviewer:

https://www.wakari.io/sharing/bundle/hrojas/How%20to%20plot%20selective%20data%20from%20a%20text%20file